Choosing between proper velocity and ordinary velocity
A question of mine on proper velocity was recently shut down so I have deleted it and decided to rephrase with focusing on more specific points. I have also checked formerly posted questions but seen that they weren't really about comparing these two concepts, but rather about just proper velocity with some of them adding proper acceleration etc.
We define proper velocity and ordinary velocity in following ways:
$$
\textbf{η} = \frac{d\textbf{x}}{d\tau}\hspace{1cm}\textbf{u}=\frac{d\textbf{x}}{dt}$$
Where $\textbf{x}$ and $t$ are displacement and time observed from an external frame, and $\tau$ is the time observed inside the frame moving with velocity $\textbf{u}$. We can thus see that the proper velocity $\textbf{η}$ mathematically has some sort of hybrid structure in terms of its parameters' belonged frames. This structure is primarily what confuses me when it comes to apply the proper velocity in examples and definitions of other concepts.
One of the example scenarios Griffiths gave was a man getting hungry during flight, since displacement of the plane is observed externally, but man's biological processes go on internally depending on the time passing in inside the plane frame, the hybrid structure fits well. But honestly I couldn't find any other physical interpretation that can be made for a hypotethical scenario where we are given the proper velocity. Therefore without a possible explicit need, I can't decide where to pick proper velocity over ordinary velocity. Could you provide a different example or a short instruction?
Another place I can't find a reason to pick proper velocity over ordinary velocity is in four-momentum's definition, other than the fact that it's proper velocity that builds a conserved momentum in relativistic collisions but that just seems like trial and error. I am not claiming that it's not enough, but I wonder, is there a way to associate the definition-wise difference between these two velocities with our preference while defining the four-momentum?

Related - Why do we differentiate a 4 vector with respect to proper time to obtain 4-velocity?

What does "pick" mean here?

@WillO using one instead of the other basically, like using proper velocity while defining four-momentum instead of ordinary velocity.

Previous post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/829718/174766


We define proper velocity and ordinary velocity in following ways:
$$
\textbf{η} = \frac{d\textbf{x}}{d\tau}\hspace{1cm}\textbf{u}=\frac{d\textbf{x}}{dt}$$
Where $\textbf{x}$ and $t$ are displacement and time observed from an external frame, and $\tau$ is the time observed inside the frame moving with velocity $\textbf{u}$.

Not only is $d\tau$ the differential of the "time observed inside the frame moving with velocity $\textbf{u}$," but is it also an invariant quantity. I.e., it is the same in every reference frame. This makes it special and useful.

I can't decide where to pick proper velocity over ordinary velocity. Could you provide a different example or a short instruction?

If you want the spatial component of the four-vector velocity you should pick the proper velocity. You might want this because of its simple and well-known Lorentz transformation properties.
If you want the ordinary Newtonian velocity you should pick the ordinary velocity. You might want this if you want to know the ordinary speed in one fixed frame.

Another place I can't find a reason to pick proper velocity over ordinary velocity is in four-momentum's definition, other than the fact that it's proper velocity that builds a conserved momentum in relativistic collisions but that just seems like trial and error.

Relativistic collisions are governed by relativistic physics equations. So, for example, if you want to simplify a calculation by transforming from a "lab" frame to a "rest" frame, you would have to use a Lorentz transformation, not a Galilean transformation.
The four-momentum defined with the proper velocity as
$$
p = m u = m(\frac{dt}{d\tau}, \frac{d\vec x}{d\tau})\;,
$$
where $m$ is the rest mass, has simple Lorentz transformation properties, since $d\tau$ does not transform (it is invariant). That is, $p$ transforms just like any other Lorentz four-vector because it is created by differentiating a four-vector with respect to an invariant $\tau$ and multiplying by an invariant (the rest mass $m$)
But if you were to try to use something like
$$
\vec p = m\frac{d\vec x}{dt}\;,
$$
this would not transform simply, since both the differential $dt$ and the differential $d\vec x$ transform.

I am not claiming that it's not enough, but I wonder, is there a way to associate the definition-wise difference between these two velocities with our preference while defining the four-momentum?

The preference is due to the simple transformation properties, which arise because $d\tau$ is invariant.

So for the second paragraph, why would I want to know the spatial component of four-velocity? Is it to extract the ordinary velocity parameter after making the transformations in a simpler way thanks to our proper velocity definition? Because I have many reasons to want the ordinary Newtonian velocity (like calculating the future location of an object in space, as the most common example) and I just can't think of any for the proper velocity.

Yes, that is one reason.
